# The 'this.props.history.push()' is working for normal page but not working for nested components?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have reactjs page called Addmember.js ,where I can add people. And I have a next button which will take me to dashboard via the following code

```
 this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
```

But the real problem arises, when I use the Add member component inside a new page, when i click next its showing the below error

Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Help will be Appreciated!

Comment: How does your nested component look like?

Comment: why not just use ```Link``` instead??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try importing **withRouter** from 'react-router-dom'

Then pass the component within withRouter

For eg.

```
export default withRouter(Addmember);
```

Comment: Perfect buddy...nailed it..Tnks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your component can not find history props when you nest it. 
Currently react-router-dom updated to the version 5, so you can use their hooks.

To solve given problem you should import useHistory hook like so `import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'`

Then use it in AddMember like `const history = useHistory()`. Then you can use all methods from history where you need it. I think it will help for you

Comment: i'm using a classing component and hooks can be only used inside functional component